# SQL join produces one result only

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

Can anyone please tell me why this result is generation only one results? taking in mind that everything is set right and the three tables are populated correctly, i took out the group_concat and it worked but of course with a php undefined index error!

```
SELECT
    `songs`.`song_name`,
    `songs`.`add_date`,
    `songs`.`song_id`,
    `songs`.`song_picture`,
    group_concat(DISTINCT artists.artist_name) as artist_name
FROM (`songs`)
JOIN `mtm_songs_artists` ON `songs`.`song_id` = `mtm_songs_artists`.`song_id`
JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`artist_id` = `mtm_songs_artists`.`artist_id`
ORDER BY `songs`.`song_id` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

so i'm guessing it's something related to group_concat.

best regards,

Rami

Comment: Please format your query onto multiple lines.

Comment: kevpie, thank you i figured it out, it seems like i had to write concat instead of group_concat

Answer (score 0):

It should be `concat` not `group_concat` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's because of the group_concat.  group_concat concatenates all items in the group... which is the entire result set if you have no GROUP BY clause.  It's a bit hard to tell how to fix the query without the schema, but I think you need to either group by artist_id or use a subquery.